# How do I draw an arc in SVG that starts out thick and gets thinner until reaching a single point?

Tags: svg

I want an arc line that goes from thick to thin, kind of like figure 13 here:

[image]

Is this possible with SVG?

Comment: do you mean by script, or do you search for inkscape? -- no, apparently not... did not read the answer...

Comment: you need to make a filled path that looks like a stroke above. A way to calculate an offset path is given here: http://processingjs.nihongoresources.com/bezierinfo/ if let tend the offset width from thick to zero for the length of your path the effect might appear. All in all i guess it is not that trivial. -- btw. could help if you tag your question with javascript and more tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with just a stroke, no. You would have to use a fill, and offset the paths slightly to get the tapering effect.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it, just draw two lines with a little offset in beginning point. Just like this:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 400">
  <path d="M 50,250 C 50,150 150,50 250,50" fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="11"></path>
  <path d="M 60,250 C 60,150 150,50 250,50" fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="11"></path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

In Inkscape, there are Triangle In and Triangle Out styles for drawing curves that look like that, and they just make a path, so I assume not.